# Cannot login to app using java-saml-toolkit

Tags: java, saml, onelogin

I've downloaded the java-saml sample project from GitHub, set it up, as per the instructions here: https://developers.onelogin.com/saml/java 
My app should be accessed like this:
http://localhost:8070/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/index.jsp
But when I start it browser opens:
http://localhost:8070/ or this: http://localhost:8070/index.jsp
I see the login page, then I am redirected to my deployed app, I enter the credentials and finally I got: HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
with this page: http://localhost:8070/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/acs.jsp

Also I cannot access my app using http://localhost:8070/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/index.jsp -> it throws me the same 404 Status.

Help me figure out what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If the base URL of your jsp example is http://localhost:8070/index.jsp instead http://localhost:8080/java-saml-tookit-jspsample/index.jsp

Then you may configure the SP urls with the right base url.

For example, ACS URL: http://localhost:8070/acs.jsp